# How do I combine 2 RegEx statements together, using JavaScript/RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been looking at RegEX's and don't know how to combine 2 regex statements together, for example

I have this JQuery code:

```
$('.numeric').keyup(function () { 
    $(this).toggleClass('field-error', /\D/.test(this.value));
});
```

How do I combine this with the regex `^0` ...means any number begining with zero

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^0|\D/
```

Use the pipe (`|`) character to symbolize you want **either** the left **or** the right side.

e.g. to match apple, orange or banana you can use:

```
/apple|orange|banana/
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked & appreciate the explanation, understand it now

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
/^0|\D/
```

Which simply matches `^0` or `\D`.